# Displaying one site collection's list in another site collection in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, 2013

I have a list which holds data in one SharePoint collection eg *dept.site.com*

I wish to display this list in another SharePoint collection eg *dept2.site.com*

- Dept2 should only be able to view the data and not edit it.
- Dept2 should only be linking to the data in dept so there is only one copy of the data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Check this link its already discussed on this site.

The DataView Web Part can help you in implementing this.

[How can I show announcements from a different site collection?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17560/how-can-i-show-announcements-from-a-different-site-collection)

Comment: Not sure about the second link. We are talking about two different site collections in my question.

Comment: oh...sorry I am removing the second link but have a look at the first link

Answer (score 1):

With SharePoint 2013, the best way to do this by far is with the Search web parts. They are so much easier to use than the older ways of showing data across sites (Content Query Web Part and Data View Web Part), more flexible and perform much better.

You should look in to the Content Search Web Part, or you can just use the standard Search Results Web Part.

Your use case is basically what is called "cross site publishing" in SharePoint terminology, and there are a lot of features to support it. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635883.aspx
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/02/18/an-introduction-to-cross-site-publishing/

Depending on your specific requirements, simply using the search web parts above may be enough, and you may not need to define catalogs etc, but you should look into to determine what is most useful in your situation.