# Insert an App part cross site collections

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-addin, site-collection, app-part

I have a web application with two site collections;

- Team site
- Enterprise wiki

Now I want to display the latest 10 enterprise wiki pages inside the team site. 
Now I try the following I went to the enterprise wiki, edit page, insert App part, select “Pages”. Then I edit the current view to display the latest 10 pages.
But seems that I cannot do the same thing steps cross site collection, because when I went to the team site collection, I can not add a App part of type enterprise wiki ?

So can anyone advice, how to add a cross-site collection app part ? i read about creating external list, but i can not understand how i can locate the related enterprise wiki tables..

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you are adding a list view web part to a page that displays all the items in the Site Pages library?  What are you trying to do with the team site? Add a list view web part to the team site's Site Pages library? Or the enterprise wiki site's Site Pages?

Comment: check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17560/how-can-i-show-announcements-from-a-different-site-collection

Comment: @wjervis what i want is to display the list of wiki pages inside the team site. where both the team site and the enterprise wikis are on separate site collections

Comment: @johnG Check the link that Waqas posted.  That will provide you with methods to accomplish that.  If you need help implementing one of them, ask a new question.

Comment: @wjervis i can not find "core result web part" under the available web parts. not sure if i can use "core result web part." inside SharePoint 2013 enterprise wiki site collection... as mentioned in the above link

Comment: Try a Search Results Web Part instead.  You can configure the results using Keyword Query Language (KQL).